# If condition on Selecting XML node in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I am trying to read the xml and storing it in SQL server.

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = 
 '<report>
    <personal>
       <search>
           <subject>
               <name>SearchName</name>
           </subject>
       </search>    
    </personal>
    <personal>
       <search>
           <subject>
               <name>SearchName</name>
           </subject>
       </search>
       <result>
           <history>
              <name>HistoryName</name>
           </history>
       </result>
    </personal>
  </report>
'
```

What i am trying here is - selecting the name but condition here is 
if `<personal>` contains `<result>` then select the `name` under `history/name`

if `<personal>` doesn't contain `<result>` select the `name` under `subject/name`

currently i am selecting names from personal/subject as below:

```
Select 
A.Search.value('(subject/name)[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM  @xml.nodes('/report/personal/search') as A(Search)
```

Expecting result:

```
SearchName
HistoryName
```

How to add condition in between?

Is there any way we can add exists condition here

```
 SELECT @xml.exist('//report//personal//search//subject//name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(
       A.Search.value('(result/history/name)[1]','varchar(max)'),
       A.Search.value('(search/subject/name)[1]','varchar(max)')
    ) AS Name
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/personal') as A(Search)
```

will return:

```
Name
------------
SearchName
HistoryName
```

Comment: @user1893874 Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select coalesce(A.Search.value('(result/history/name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), A.Search.value('(search/subject/name)[1]','varchar(max)'))
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/personal') as A(Search)
```

Comment: It returns SearchName but i want to get both SearchName and HistoryName in a single query

Comment: Yes, that is what i am looking for. Thank you :)